# Taking FFT of a signal with lots of "holes"

Tags: fft

I have a time series that is spotty (more 'no sample' than 'sample' at each second, which is the sample rate).  There are obvious trends when viewed visually.  However since there are holes, the FFT has a spike near zero.  Is there anything that I can do about this?

Comment: Could you post a photo of your FFT plot?

Comment: what are you looking for in your FFT result?

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz I can see (visually) that the data is periodic by day and by season.  Every day it peaks at noon, and early in the AM there is no data (no activity).  So I'd like a spike at the day frequency, and at the month frequency.  But my average is very small because of all the zeros (no data for that sample)

Comment: you could try Lomb-Scargle https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-squares_spectral_analysis

Comment: Given you said that you have a spike near zero, do you mean near zero frequency? If at zero frequency then this is a result of DC Offset (non-zero mean), which can be eliminated simply by subtracting the mean.

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz would you make this an answer?

Comment: @horsehair posting a link isn’t really the quality of answer that the regulars here typically respect. i think that the Wikipedia article would be hard to improve given the time i could devote to the task right now.

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz - just that your comment helped me out and I wanted you to get credit for it.  Thanks, in any case.

Comment: @horsehair you’re welcome